# What were the comments on this question?

Tags: support

[Word for "about the way everything is connected"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/581562/163011)

The comments were moved to chat, but the chat only has one comment (the same one as is on the question right now)

What were all the comments beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

The old comments were deleted as policy violations.

All the (other) comments beforehand were answers misposted to the comment box by members who know better.

Any in good standing are free to post their answers using the answer box where such belong.